# IE7 strange background-position behavior

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have two labels with the same class. It is my css of this class:

```
.required
{
    background-image:url(/img/required.png);
    background-position: right;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding-right:10px;
}
```

In all browsers two elements has red star in right-top. But in IE 7 only first element has this star. What I am doing wrong? Please help me.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with that code. Could you provide a link to a working example? (perhaps on jsfiddle.com if you can't show us your actualy site)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Alexander.Plutov: Using a `required.png` which I *[borrowed](http://tickets.prysmgroup.co.uk/images/required.png)*  for the exercise, the following code sample seems to work fine (I just condensed your `CSS` rules to the shorthand version):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>

<style type="text/css">
.required
{
    background: url(img/required.png) no-repeat right top;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<form action="4430474.htm" method="post">
    <div>
        <label for="field1" class="required">Field 1:</label>
        <input type="text" name="field1" id="field1" size="40" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="field2" class="required">Field 2:</label>
        <input type="text" name="field2" id="field2" size="40" />
    </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Do you perhaps employ any `float` or `position` rules for anything in your form? These are usually the things that misbehave in IE6/7.

Comment: Really thanks. Your note about position in form is correct. My form has UI-dialog class. And this class has css rule `position: relative`. if i remove UI class all OK. But I need this class(

Comment: @Alexander.Plutov: If you comment out just that line `/* position: relative */` in your `CSS`, you should be able to keep the other styles intact. Alternative, check out this answer since it may also be a `DOCTYPE` issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945660/jquery-ui-dialog-when-opened-ie7-browser-moves-instantly-to-the-bottom-of-the-p/2976833#2976833

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this would change anything, but have you tried

```
label .required 
{css here}
```